# Magento 1.9: Maximum execution timeout after login

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, memory, timeout, php-7.1

**Description**:

After a customer logs into my shop, the script receives a stack overflow, execution timeout or exhausted memory size. But only at one store view (en_GB).
***I guess it's a loop***. I have only one magento-website with one store and a few store views. They are identical except for language/localization and each of them use the same templates etc. It doesn't matter which page I want to open in this store view (en_GB), it's always the same problem. If you log in to another store view and everything works and you change to this special store ID (en_GB), it's broken again until you delete all cookies. The status of the visitor is important: Without a logged-in user, the entire shop functions perfectly and you can change the shop IDs as many times as you want.

**My setup**:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx 1.14
- PHP 7.1
- HAProxy 1.88
- Magento 1.9.3.9 & PHP 7.2 PATCH
- Redis 4.0.9 & MariaDB 10.1.34 (on another server)

After the update of PHP and the increase of the memory limit, there are only exceptions to the maximum execution time. I guess after 30 seconds it's random which message is displayed.

**Error Messages**:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 1012[, 821, 1139]
```

or

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 625
```

or

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 195
```

or

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php on line 479
```

or

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Locale/Math.php on line 244
```

or

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php on line 255
```

or

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 431
```

There are no exceptions in the Magento logs. I don't know how to properly debug that. I've already deleted all caches and reindexed the database.

**What I've already done**:

- Delete all cookies and try again.
- Create new user in special store view (en_GB) and use its credentials. It works for this special store view (en_GB), but the change to another store view (e.g. de_DE) killed it again. It's the other way round.
- Activate and deactivate persistent shopping cart.
- Activate and deactivate session validation: Use SID in Frontend
- Change session storage from file to redis.
- Update SQL and PHP.

I've checked the general query log of SQL and found the following queries over and over again, maybe it's suspicious and give a hint. They occurred at the main page with a few widgets in a cms-page that are linking to the categories.

```
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `status_table` ON main_table.product_id=status_table.product_id AND main_table.stock_id=status_table.stock_id AND status_table.website_id='1' WHERE (`main_table`.`stock_id` = '1') AND (`main_table`.`product_id` IN('47881'))
            6 Query SELECT `catalogrule_product_price`.`product_id`, `catalogrule_product_price`.`rule_price` FROM `catalogrule_product_price` WHERE (rule_date = '2018-09-28') AND (website_id = '1') AND (customer_group_id = '0') AND (product_id IN('47881'))
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (`quote_address_id` = '78723')
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (`quote_address_id` = '78724')
            6 Query SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`is_percent` FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE (entity_id='47881') AND (website_id = 0)
            6 Query SELECT `sales_flat_quote`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote` WHERE (`sales_flat_quote`.`entity_id`='39295') AND (store_id IN ('1', '4', '5', '3', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '2', '11', '12', '13', '15', '14')) AND (is_active = 1)
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address` AS `main_table` WHERE (`quote_id` = '39295')
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (`quote_id` = '39295')
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AS `main_table` WHERE (`item_id` IN(81750))
            6 Query SELECT DISTINCT ea.attribute_code FROM `salesrule_product_attribute` AS `a`
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `ea` ON ea.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
            6 Query SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(47881, 47881))
            6 Query SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 2 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (47881)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('71', '98', '97', '87', '86', '118', '119', '122', '130')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 2 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (47881)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('96', '102', '121', '100', '126', '123', '127', '125', '124', '128')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 2 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (47881)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('75', '80', '76', '120')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 2 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (47881)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('77', '78')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 2 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (47881)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('101')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0)
            6 Query SELECT `cataloginventory_stock_status`.`product_id`, `cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status` WHERE (product_id IN('47881')) AND (stock_id=1) AND (website_id=1)
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.*, `default_option_title`.`title` AS `default_title`, `store_option_title`.`title` AS `store_title`, IF(store_option_title.title IS NULL, default_option_title.title, store_option_title.title) AS `title`, `default_option_price`.`price` AS `default_price`, `default_option_price`.`price_type` AS `default_price_type`, `store_option_price`.`price` AS `store_price`, `store_option_price`.`price_type` AS `store_price_type`, IF(store_option_price.price IS NULL, default_option_price.price, store_option_price.price) AS `price`, IF(store_option_price.price_type IS NULL, default_option_price.price_type, store_option_price.price_type) AS `price_type` FROM `catalog_product_option` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option_title` AS `default_option_title` ON default_option_title.option_id = main_table.option_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_title` AS `store_option_title` ON store_option_title.option_id = main_table.option_id AND store_option_title.store_id = '2'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_price` AS `default_option_price` ON default_option_price.option_id = main_table.option_id AND default_option_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_price` AS `store_option_price` ON store_option_price.option_id = main_table.option_id AND store_option_price.store_id = '2' WHERE (default_option_title.store_id = 0) AND (`product_id` IN('47881'))
            6 Query SELECT `core_url_rewrite`.`product_id`, `core_url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE (store_id = 2) AND (is_system = 1) AND (category_id = 0 OR category_id IS NULL) AND (product_id IN('47881')) ORDER BY `category_id` DESC
            6 Query SELECT `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`qty` AS `price_qty`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`value` AS `price`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`entity_id` AS `product_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` WHERE (entity_id IN('47881')) AND (website_id = 0) ORDER BY `entity_id` ASC, `qty` ASC
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.*, `cp_table`.`type_id`, `status_table`.`stock_status` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cp_table` ON main_table.product_id = cp_table.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `status_table` ON main_table.product_id=status_table.product_id AND main_table.stock_id=status_table.stock_id AND status_table.website_id='1' WHERE (`main_table`.`stock_id` = '1') AND (`main_table`.`product_id` IN('47881'))
            6 Query SELECT `catalogrule_product_price`.`product_id`, `catalogrule_product_price`.`rule_price` FROM `catalogrule_product_price` WHERE (rule_date = '2018-09-28') AND (website_id = '1') AND (customer_group_id = '0') AND (product_id IN('47881'))
            6 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (`quote_address_id` = '78723')
```

If you need more information, please let me know and thank you in advance!

---

### Edit (24.10.2018):

After re-generating the "en_gb" store view, I saw this loop behavior when changing the currency to Pounds in the configuration. When I use Euro as my default currency in this store view, everything works fine. Any ideas how i can debug this?